# What happens in lasik operation?

Tags: eyes, human-eye, surgery

First of all,I am very bad at biology. So please bear if it sounds elementary.

I heard about lasik operation for reshaping cornea.

Assume the patient is suffering from myopia implying lens is thicker than expected.So if i think logically ,to correct the lens thickness ,lens must be reduced.

In lasik, do they cut the lens's tissue.If yes what happens to the part that is cut and if no then how exactly lens thickness is reduced?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible ways to perform refractive operation: first,  to perform the procedure on the cornea, the second - to exchange the crystalline lens with the artificial one.

The second approach is extremely rare, because the lens (1) is inside the eye and (2) it allows us to accommodate (=change the focus of vision). Thus, this method is relevant only to extremely high myops and people who have some degree of cataract (the clouding of the lens).

In "classic" myopia the eye is larger than "normal" one, and the lens thickness is less relevant in the terms of treatment.

Back to LASIK - the operation is performed on the cornea: for myopic eye the corneal thickness should be reduced, for hyperopic eye there are other protocols (special thickness reduction).

[image]